# Access Session Bean Property/Inject Session Bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ejb

Still learning JSF and Java and having trouble understanding how to access a session bean property. 
I have a `LoggedUser` session bean which sets the user that is logged in(using the login method).

```
@ManagedBean(name="loggedUser")
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoggedUser {

    @EJB
    UserEJB userEJB;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    private UserEntity loggedUser;
    private String loginUserName;
    private String loginPassword;

    public LoggedUser() {}

    public UserEntity getLoggedUser() {
        return loggedUser;
    }

    public void setLoggedUser(UserEntity loggedUser) {
        this.loggedUser = loggedUser;
    }

    public String authenticate() {
        if (loggedUser == null) {
            return "login.xhtml";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public String login() {
        if (userEJB.validateLogin(loginUserName, loginPassword)) {
            setLoggedUser(userEJB.fetchUser(loginUserName));
            return "index.xhtml";
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String getLoginUserName() {
        return loginUserName;
    }

    public void setLoginUserName(String loginUserName) {
        this.loginUserName = loginUserName;
    }

    public String getLoginPassword() {
        return loginPassword;
    }

    public void setLoginPassword(String loginPassword) {
        this.loginPassword = loginPassword;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to view the logged user from other areas in the application. I think I am injecting it incorrectly because loggedUser is always null when I am in a different bean for example something like..

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class HistoryEJB {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{loggedUser}")
    private LoggedUser loggedUser;

    public LoggedUser getLoggedUser() {
        return loggedUser;
    }

    public void setLoggedUser(LoggedUser loggedUser) {
        this.loggedUser = loggedUser;
    }

    public void testLoggedUser() {
        loggedUser.getLoggedUser();
        // Just an example but would be null here - why?
    }
}
```

How can I access this property from other areas in my application? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `@ManagedProperty` in an EJB and you shouldn't inject a view component into a business-tier component, period. `@ManagedProperty` is strictly web-tier stuff and is able to inject only and into web-tier, JSF components.

Your EJB ought to have a method that accepts a `LoggedUser`. This way, you can then pass your logged-in user to the EJB (which is the proper flow of data in a web application). What you have now is just turning best practice on its head.

So

1. Add a `provideLoggedUser(LoggedUser loggedUser)` method to your EJB
2. Call that method on your instance of `UserEJB` from within your managed bean

**Rule of Thumb:** *Your EJB should not be aware of the web application*

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are missing the setter and getter for loggedUser. In principe it is there but it is convention to name it as follows

```
setProperty
```

and

```
setProperty
```

for a field named `property`. Note the capital first letter of the field name in the setter and getter!

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to change those back. Wouldn't be the reason I'm having this problem though right?

Comment: I guess you get an exception, as it cannot be set. If not, I would be surprised.